# Initialising new rails project after upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.2

I have been working on Ruby on rails project for a while now, when I followed the instructions in the newest instalment of Agile Web Development in Rails and installed the newest edition of Ruby. Before I only used the version that comes with OSX Lion, but with rvm I have installed this version:

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

When I set this to execute using e.g. irb this works great, also running scripts with the ruby command line tool works good.

My problem is that when I start a new project with 'rails new', or run the server or the console, rails won't work. I have the Rails 3.2.3 version.

The error stacks is as follows:

```
BigMac:Coding ola$ rails new depot
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install

/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation  fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0038 p:---- s:0217 b:0217 l:000216 d:000216 CFUNC  :connect
c:0037 p:0011 s:0214 b:0214 l:0019a0 d:000213 BLOCK  /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-    p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799
c:0036 p:0031 s:0212 b:0212 l:000211 d:000211 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3- p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54
c:0035 p:0026 s:0200 b:0200 l:000199 d:000199 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99
c:0034 p:0485 s:0194 b:0194 l:0019a0 d:0019a0 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799
c:0033 p:0011 s:0186 b:0186 l:000185 d:000185 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755
c:0032 p:0089 s:0183 b:0183 l:000182 d:000182 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750
c:0031 p:0340 s:0180 b:0180 l:000179 d:000179 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:224
c:0030 p:0157 s:0172 b:0172 l:000171 d:000171 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3- p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358
c:0029 p:0081 s:0158 b:0158 l:000157 d:000157 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:135
c:0028 p:0105 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:163
c:0027 p:0141 s:0140 b:0140 l:000139 d:000139 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:122
c:0026 p:0178 s:0130 b:0130 l:000129 d:000129 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70
c:0025 p:0042 s:0122 b:0122 l:000111 d:000121 BLOCK  /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:234
c:0024 p:---- s:0117 b:0117 l:000116 d:000116 FINISH
c:0023 p:---- s:0115 b:0115 l:000114 d:000114 CFUNC  :each
c:0022 p:0079 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:232
 c:0021 p:0018 s:0102 b:0102 l:000101 d:000101 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:165
 c:0020 p:0025 s:0098 b:0098 l:000097 d:000097 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:70
c:0019 p:0059 s:0095 b:0094 l:000076 d:000093 BLOCK  /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:205
c:0018 p:---- s:0090 b:0090 l:000089 d:000089 FINISH
c:0017 p:---- s:0088 b:0088 l:000087 d:000087 CFUNC  :each
c:0016 p:0043 s:0085 b:0085 l:000076 d:000084 BLOCK  /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202
c:0015 p:0020 s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-  p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/index.rb:9
c:0014 p:0031 s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:198
c:0013 p:0139 s:0074 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192
 c:0012 p:0027 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127
 c:0011 p:0047 s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122
 c:0010 p:0303 s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48
 c:0009 p:0033 s:0051 b:0051 l:000050 d:000050 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12
 c:0008 p:0978 s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220
  c:0007 p:0036 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22
  c:0006 p:0071 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118
  c:0005 p:0221 s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263
  c:0004 p:0082 s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 METHOD /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3 -p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386
  c:0003 p:0054 s:0007 b:0007 l:001ba8 d:0024a0 EVAL   /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/bin/bundle:13
   c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
    c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001ba8 d:001ba8 TOP   

  -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
  /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/bin/bundle:13:in `<main>'
  /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-    1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in  `install'
 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
  /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48:in `run'
  /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:198:in `index'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `block in index'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `each'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:205:in `block (2 levels) in index'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:122:in `fetch_remote_specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:163:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:135:in `fetch'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:224:in `connection_for'
/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
/Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/bin/bundle

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/rbconfig.rb
    5 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ubygems.rb
   10 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
   11 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
   12 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
   13 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
   14 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
   15 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb
   16 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/etc.bundle
   17 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
   18 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/pathname.bundle
   19 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
   20 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/syntax_error.rb
   21 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/psych.bundle
   22 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/stringio.bundle
   23 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb
   24 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb
   25 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/document.rb
   26 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/sequence.rb
   27 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/scalar.rb
   28 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
   29 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/alias.rb
   30 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes.rb
   31 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/streaming.rb
   32 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
   33 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/strscan.bundle
   34 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/scalar_scanner.rb
   35 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
   36 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
   37 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb
   38 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/ruby_events.rb
   39 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/json_tree.rb
   40 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/depth_first.rb
   41 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors.rb
   42 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/handler.rb
   43 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/tree_builder.rb
   44 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/parser.rb
   45 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/omap.rb
   46 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/set.rb
   47 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/coder.rb
   48 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/core_ext.rb
   49 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/date_core.bundle
   50 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb
   51 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
   52 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/deprecated.rb
   53 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/stream.rb
   54 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/yaml_events.rb
   55 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
   56 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/stream.rb
   57 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
   58 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb
   59 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb
   60 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/psyched_yaml.rb
   61 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   62 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   63 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   64 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb
   65 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/psych_additions.rb
   66 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/psych_tree.rb
   67 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/syck_hack.rb
   68 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   69 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/version.rb
   70 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb
   71 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/core_ext/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb
   72 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/core_ext/ordered_hash.rb
   73 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/error.rb
   74 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell.rb
   75 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb
   76 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/argument.rb
   77 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/arguments.rb
   78 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/option.rb
   79 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/options.rb
   80 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser.rb
   81 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb
   82 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/util.rb
   83 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb
   84 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb
   85 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb
   86 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb
   87 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ftp.rb
   88 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb
   89 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/https.rb
   90 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldap.rb
   91 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldaps.rb
   92 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/mailto.rb
   93 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri.rb
   94 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/core_ext/file_binary_read.rb
   95 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb
   96 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/create_file.rb
   97 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/create_link.rb
   98 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/directory.rb
   99 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb
  100 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
  101 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb
  102 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb
  103 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb
  104 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions.rb
  105 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendored_thor.rb
  106 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
  107 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb
  108 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/delegate.rb
  109 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb
  110 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/thread.rb
  111 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb
  112 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb
  113 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/color.rb
  114 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/ui.rb
  115 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb
  116 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
  117 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/socket.bundle
  118 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
  119 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb
  120 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb
  121 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/zlib.bundle
  122 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb
  123 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/faster.rb
  124 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/core.rb
  125 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/cookie.rb
  126 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb
  127 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi.rb
  128 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb
  129 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb
  130 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb
  131 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_list.rb
  132 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/f_sync_dir.rb
  133 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_header.rb
  134 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/enc/iso_8859_1.bundle
  135 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb
  136 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_output.rb
  137 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb
  138 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb
  139 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb
  140 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package.rb
  141 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb
  142 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb
  143 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/configure_builder.rb
  144 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb
  145 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb
  146 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb
  147 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/rake_builder.rb
  148 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext.rb
  149 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/require_paths_builder.rb
  150 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb
  151 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
  152 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/errors.rb
  153 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/text.rb
  154 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
  155 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb
  156 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb
  157 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb
  158 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/digest.bundle
  159 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest.rb
  160 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/digest/sha1.bundle
  161 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb
  162 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb
  163 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
  164 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
  165 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb
  166 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/gem_installer.rb
  167 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb
  168 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb
  169 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
  170 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb
  171 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
  172 /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/index.rb
  173 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/openssl.bundle
  174 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/bn.rb
  175 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/cipher.rb
  176 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/config.rb
  177 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/digest.rb
  178 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb
  179 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/fcntl.bundle
  180 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb
  181 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/x509-internal.rb
  182 /Users/ola/.rvm/rubi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just happened to me the same, probably you are using rvm + macports.
I found the solution in the RVM documentation: https://rvm.io/integration/macports/

> In order to use MacPorts libraries when installing RVM Rubies, set the
>   following variables in your $HOME/.rvmrc:
>
> ```
> export CFLAGS="-O2 -arch x86_64"
> export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include"
> ```

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-opt-dir=/opt/local
```

Comment: Me too.  I actually did "rvm reinstall" instead of "rvm install".

Answer (score 1):

Try `gem update bundler` once before doing this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this, but it didn't solve the problem. I still get the same error message.